# Bash programs that checks folder and copies folders/files that doesen't exist there

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to make bash script for ubuntu that will check for files in folder Downloads and copy everything that doesen't exist in Documents to Documents. But I'm stuck at checking if file exist, can somebody help me out?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/rene/Downloads
for file in *
do  
  echo $file
  if [ ! -f /home/rene/Documents/$file ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
  fi
done
```

Comment: How about using `rsync` instead?  That is made to perform such tasks.

Comment: Before going any further, [you need to quote your variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).

Comment: If all you need is "copy if it's not already there", even `cp` has a flag for that.

Comment: is it possible with rsync that if I delete something in documents won't get Deleted in downloads?

Comment: Yes, it's easy with `cp` or `rsync` to not remove files from the destination which don't exist at the source. Not really a programming question, though. Peruse the manuals, perhaps?

Comment: Looks like I complicated too much, thank you all